# Capture and recall the state of radio button groups using cookies and as little jQuery as possible

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cookies, radio-button

Just a day ago I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946680/parsing-multi-variable-cookies-into-web-form-values) and found/built my own solution, for lack of a sufficient answer. Now, I need help going through a similar process again. This time, however, I need to capture (save to cookie as 'Base64' data) and recall (recheck upon user return) the state of all the radio button groups (by 'name' not 'ID', for obvious reasons), after the page loads, and if need be trigger all corresponding onchange events attached to them. For example, if a radio button group label has the question, "Have you lived at this address for more than 3 years?' one radio button label says 'Yes', and the other, 'No'. If the user chooses 'No' an extra 'address' table row is displayed in the table. All of the mechanics of the table appearing on 'No' 'checked' has already been done. I'm looking for a simple way to:

A:) Record all radio button group(s) state(s) (i.e which one is checked), on the 'onchange' event of any radio button on the form.

B:) Convert that information to JSON or some other record keeping

C:) Base64 encode data in step [B:]

D:) Save to a cookie

Upon page reload (user returns to page)...

E:) Grab data from cookie

F:) Decode Base64 and assign to variable

G:) From data iterate through all the forms radio buttons re-checking what was originally checked.

Sound easy? Give it a try! I did....and am still.

Comment: You got a sample or something to work from? Perhaps a jsfiddle?

Comment: @cgatian No, I don't have a workable jsfiddle. Please start from my lead posted [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946680/parsing-multi-variable-cookies-into-web-form-values)

Comment: It doesn't matter if your fiddle works. Show us what you've got.

Comment: I told you its not working but if you insist, [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesAndersonJr/AE7XY/1/).

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski This kind of code uses domain cookies and is to complicated to run in jsfiddle. It won't even work with the [ORIGINAL CODE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946680/parsing-multi-variable-cookies-into-web-form-values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the basics in jQuery without the cookie saving, will leave that to you

```
var radioState={};
$(':radio').each(function(){
    if(!radioState[this.name]){
        radioState[this.name]={};
    }    
    radioState[this.name][this.value]=this.checked
});


/* stringify to JSOn and convert to Base64 */
var storeString= btoa(JSON.stringify(radioState));

/* store in cookie*/

/* on page load pull data from cookie (if exists) - add a cookie validation test*/
var cookieString=storeString;// just using this for demo


var newPageState= JSON.parse(atob(cookieString));
/* loop through radios setting state */
$(':radio').prop('checked',function(){
    return newPageState[this.name][this.value];    
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Yv4gL/4/)**</kbd>

[`atob()` and `btoa()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Base64_encoding_and_decoding)

**EDIT**: Use localStorage if browser supported, with cookie fallback. Will minimize cookie size sent to server for each and every http request made to site

Comment: Thanks! You're a genius! Code works perfectly except for one thing...when the radio buttons are remembered and checked, their corresponding onchange events are not fired. But that's a small issue quickly remedied by a few extra 'if' statements in either an external js file of on the HTML/PHP page itself. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

Thank You @Charlietfl. +1! Here is the complete **'save_form.js'** code!

```
//<!-- Prerequisites: jquery.min.js -->

//<!-- A script to set a cookie [Argument(s) accepted: Cookie Name, Cookie Value, etc.] [BEGIN] -->
function set_cookie ( name, value, path, domain, secure )
    {
        var cookie_string = name + "=" + escape ( value );

        var cookie_date = new Date();  // current date & time ;

        var cookie_date_num = cookie_date.getTime(); // convert cookie_date to milliseconds ;
        cookie_date_num += 35 * 60 * 1000;  // add 35 minutes in milliseconds ;
        cookie_date.setTime(cookie_date_num); // set my_date Date object 35 minutes forward ;


        cookie_string += "; expires=" + cookie_date.toGMTString();


        if ( path )
            cookie_string += "; path=" + escape ( path );

        if ( domain )
            cookie_string += "; domain=" + escape ( domain );

        if ( secure )
            cookie_string += "; secure";

        document.cookie = cookie_string;

    };
//<!-- A script to set a cookie [Argument(s) accepted: Cookie Name, Cookie Value, etc.] [END] -->

//<!-- A script to grab a cookies value by name [Argument(s) accepted: Cookies Name] [BEGIN] -->

function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
    {
        var results = document.cookie.match ( '(^|;) ?' + cookie_name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)' );

        if ( results )
            { 
            return ( unescape ( results[2] ) ); 
            }
    else
            {
            return null;
            };
    };

//<!-- A script to grab a cookies value by name [Argument(s) accepted: Cookies Name] [END] -->


function populateCookieFromForm ( cookieName ) {

    var encodedCookie;

    var preCookieObj = '{';

    var allMainElements = $('form').find('input[type=text], select');

    for (var i=0; i < allMainElements.length; i++) 
        {

            preCookieObj = preCookieObj + '"' + allMainElements[i].name +'":"'+ allMainElements[i].value +'",';     

        };

    preCookieObj = preCookieObj.substring(0, preCookieObj.length - 1);
    preCookieObj = preCookieObj + '}';

    //<!-- btoa() encodes 'string' argument into Base64 encoding --> 
    encodedCookie = btoa( preCookieObj );

    set_cookie(cookieName, encodedCookie);

};

function populateFormFromCookie (cookieName) {


    if ( ! get_cookie ( cookieName ) )

        {

        //<!-- Do Nothing - No Cookie For this form set. -->

        }
    else 
        {
            //<!-- atob() decodes 'string' argument from Base64 encoding --> 
            jSONCookieObj = atob( get_cookie ( cookieName ) ) ;     

            jSONObj = JSON.parse( jSONCookieObj );

            var allMainElements = $('form').find('input[type=text], select');

            for (var i=0; i < allMainElements.length; i++)  
            {

                var elementName = allMainElements[i].name;

                var elementValue = jSONObj[elementName];

                allMainElements[i].value = elementValue;

            };

        };


};


function populateCookieFromRadios (cookieName) {
    var radioState={};

    $(':radio').each(function(){
    if(!radioState[this.name]){
    radioState[this.name]={};
    }    
    radioState[this.name][this.value]=this.checked;
    });


    /* stringify to JSON and convert to Base64 */
    var storeString= btoa(JSON.stringify(radioState));

    /* store in cookie*/
    set_cookie(cookieName, storeString);

};


function populateRadiosFromCookie (cookieName) {

    if ( ! get_cookie ( cookieName ) )

        {

        //<!-- Do Nothing - No Cookie For this form set. -->

        }

    else
        {

            var cookieString = get_cookie ( cookieName );
            var newPageState= JSON.parse(atob(cookieString));

            /* loop through radios setting state */
            $(':radio').prop('checked',function(){
            return newPageState[this.name][this.value];    
            });

        };
};
```

This is how you properly call these functions. Near the bottom of the HTML/PHP page containing the form, place this JavaScript respectively:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//<!-- If returning user detected, populate form with cookie values [BEGIN] -->

populateFormFromCookie('thisForm');
populateRadiosFromCookie('thisFormRadios');
//<!-- If returning user detected, populate form with 'section' cookie values [END] -->

//<!-- On change of ALL form elements re-save form cookie(s) [BEGIN] -->

$('input[type=radio]', $('form')).on('change',function(e){

        populateCookieFromRadios('thisFormRadios');

    });

$('input[type=text], select, textarea', $('form')).on('change',function(e){

        populateCookieFromForm('thisForm');

    });

$('input[type=text]', $('form')).on('input',function(e){     

        populateCookieFromForm('thisForm');

    });
//<!-- On change of ALL form elements re-save form cookie(s) [END] -->

</script>
```

**The next task is to see if all of this can be done without jQuery...hmm...**

Comment: shouldn't have asked for jquery...can be changed, not tonight by me though